# Rotations and angular momentum

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, angular-momentum, rotation

Cohen tannoudji. Vol 1.pg 702

> "Now, let us consider an infinitesimal rotation $\mathscr{R}_{\mathbf{e}_z}(\mathrm{~d} \alpha)$ about the $O z$ axis. Since the group law is conserved for infinitesimal rotations, the operator $R_{\mathbf{e}_z}(\mathrm{~d} \alpha)$ is necessarily of the form: $$ R_{\mathbf{e}_z}(\mathrm{~d} \alpha)=1-\frac{i}{\hbar} \mathrm{d} \alpha J_z $$ where $J_z$ is a Hermitian operator since $R_{\mathbf{e}_z}\left(\mathrm{~d} \alpha\right.$) is unitary (cf. Complement $\mathrm{C}_{\mathrm{II}}, \S 3$ ). This relation is the definition of $J_z$."

Why is it that; Since the group law is conserved for infinitesimal rotations, the operator $R_{\mathbf{e}_z}(\mathrm{~d} \alpha)$ is necessarily of the form: $$ R_{\mathbf{e}_z}(\mathrm{~d} \alpha)=1-\frac{i}{\hbar} \mathrm{d} \alpha J_z $$ where $J_z$ is a Hermitian operator?

Comment: Your expression has to be linear in dα (infinitesimal, so ignore square thereof) and reduce to the identity for dα=0. Impose the unitarity condition on it, and conclude that $J_z$ is Hermitian.

Comment: Thank you professor. Thank you. The author stresses that"Since the group law is conserved for infinitesimal rotations..." . Where does that enter the proof? Why does the author stress that. Can you please help

Comment: Unitarily. It’s a plain rotation…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition an infinitesimal transformation differs from the identity by a small amount so it must be linear in $d\alpha$ and of the form
$$
1+(\text{something about $\hat z$})d\alpha
$$
so that, when $d\alpha\to 0$, you recover the identity.  By definition, the "something about $\hat z$" is proportional to the generator of infinitesimal transformation, which here is denoted by ${\hat J}_z$. The proportionality factor is somewhat conventional.

You could absorb the $\hbar$ factor in the definition of $\hat J_z$, but in physics this factor is taken out.  Likewise, the $i$ factor is physics tradition.

To see that
$$
R_z(d\alpha)=1-\frac{i}\hbar d\alpha J_z
$$
leads to a Hermitian $J_z$, consider
$$
R_z^{-1}(d\alpha)=R_z^{\dagger}(d\alpha)=1+\frac{i}\hbar d\alpha J^\dagger_z \tag{1}
$$
which holds for unitary representations.  Then clearly
$$
R_z^{\dagger}(d\alpha)=R_z(-d\alpha)\quad \Rightarrow\quad 
1+\frac{i}\hbar d\alpha J^\dagger_z = 1+\frac{i}\hbar d\alpha J_z \tag{2}
$$
from which $\hat J_z=\hat J^\dagger_z$ follows.

Alternatively, multiply
\begin{align}
R_z\cdot R_z^{-1}=1 &= \left(1-\frac{i}\hbar d\alpha J_z\right)\left(1+\frac{i}\hbar d\alpha J^\dagger_z\right)\, ,\\
&= 1 -\frac{i}\hbar d\alpha (J_z-J_z^\dagger)+{\cal O}^2(d\alpha)
\end{align}
which also implies $J_z=J_z^\dagger$.

With this definition (and similar definitions for $\hat J_y$ and $\hat J_x$), you recover the commutation relations used in the physics literature, *v.g.*
$$
[\hat J_x,\hat J_y]=i\hbar \hat J_z
$$

Comment: Thank you. The author stresses that"Since the group law is conserved for infinitesimal rotations..." . Where does that enter the proof? Why does the author stress that. Can you please help

Comment: For a full rotation $R(\alpha)$ contains terms beyond linear, *i.e.* also contain terms in $(-i \alpha J_z/\hbar)^2$ and higher powers.  An infinitesimal rotation is still a rotation so the composition law still holds although calculations are not as complicated because only the linear parts are kept.